# Integrating extjs 3.4 and google chart api

Tags: extjs, google-visualization

First of all I am newbie .I need some help with integrating Ext js 3.4 and google chart api.
I am trying to add google pie chart to an Ext.FormPanel
I created a panel with the following code

```
 var grid = new Ext.FormPanel({
        id:'test',
          renderTo: 'panel',
          title:'Sign up',
          bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px;',
          frame: true,
          width:500,
         height:500
        });
```

The following code tries to add pie chart to the above panel.

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);


    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('test'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Fire bug is giving me error message as

“Container is not defined”.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a div with an id of container in your html body.